# Helm Projectile file limit

Tags: helm, projectile

I'm using helm with projectile. When i hit `C-c p f` - `helm-projectile-find-file` it shows no more then 100 files, turning off the caching doesn't help. I like to combine this with `helm-occur`, when i filter a bunch of files, hit `M-a` to select them all, then 'C-s` to search occurrence in these files, so i wonder if it shows only 100 does it find occurrences in all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the variable `helm-candidate-number-limit` is what you're looking for.

> Documentation:
>   Limit candidate number globally.
>   Do not show more candidates than this limit from individual sources.
>   It is usually pointless to show hundreds of matches
>   when the pattern is empty, because it is much simpler to type a
>   few characters to narrow down the list of potential candidates.

The default is 100...

Answer (score 2):

`C-s` runs `helm-grep` on selected files, not `helm-occur`. You can already perform grep/ack/ag with `helm-projectile-grep/ack/ag`. Just run one of those command, and it will search across project directory. See demos and more info in [my Helm Projectile guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html#sec-9).

I suggest you shouldn't change the default `100` or smaller, otherwise you should disable fuzzy-matching by adding `(setq helm-projectile-fuzzy-match nil)` before `(require 'helm-projectile)` because the more candidates are displayed, the slower fuzzy matching. This number is suggested by Helm maintainer.

Comment: Reading your guide on a daily bases, to master my helm+projectile skills. You are right, it runs `helm-grep`, but when i'm trying to run `helm-projectile-(grep|ag)` `C-c p s g` it doesn't show me anything, even from the current file.

Comment: What OS and Emacs are you using? If you are on Windows, you should make Emacs see external GNU Grep from Cygwin or [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) or [Msys2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/).

Comment: Using latest emacs-mac from homebrew. You know just tried `helm-projectile-grep` and it worked, but it took 2+ minutes on a big project. I'm not using `projectile-cache`, probably i should turn it on?

Comment: You should start ignoring files using one of the four variables, otherwise grep will search for everything which takes a long time, and `helm-projectile-grep` cannot go faster than `grep` itself. Note that if you add something to `projectile-globally-ignore-files/directories` variables, those files and directories are also excluded in the file list in `helm-projectile-find-file`. Better using [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) for large projects. With ag available, using `helm-projectile-ag` gives you results instantly, even for projects with more than 30k files.

Answer (score 0):

```
(setq helm-candidate-number-limit n)
```

replace n with your desired number